# d3- update barchart when click select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I've written a d3 bar chart to display special data when I click on a select option. But it doesn't work and I don't know what happened.
I can get correct data ,however it doesn't display.

Here is my project code  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23572132/

Here is an example chart from my project: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23571926/.

Here is the picture:
[image]

I've fixed some error, but the x and y axis was not update.
all the extra data display in the first chart rectangle.
key code [paste.ubuntu.com/23581882](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23581882) 
it display like [image: that]

Comment: @echonax jQuery can get selector option value: $('#queryDays').change(function(){
         days=$(this).children('option:selected').val();
        alert(days+"bar");

    });

Comment: @ echonax  also in d3:  d3.select("#queryDays").on("change", function)

Comment: I see that you've updated your question. You haven't provided the second link when I've commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an update function. The update function does the following:

Here data is the selected dataset.

```
   //update  x and y axis domain
      xScale.rangeRoundBands([d3.min(data), width - padding.left - padding.right]);
      yScale.domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]) //定义域
        //update the x and y axis
      d3.selectAll(".x").call(xAxis);
      d3.selectAll(".y").call(yAxis);
```

Now we will make the rectangle for new data:

```
 //remove all the rectangles
  svg.selectAll(".MyRect").remove();
  //append rectangles with new data
  svg.selectAll(".MyRect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "#4285F4")
    .attr("class", "MyRect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + "," + padding.top + ")")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i) + rectPadding / 2;
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand() - rectPadding)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      var min = yScale.domain()[0];
      return yScale(min);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return 0;
    })
```

Similarly for text.

Now on change of the text in select call the update like below:

```
d3.select("#queryDays").on("change", function() {
  var v = d3.select(this)[0][0].value;
  if (v == 30) {
    update(dataset3)
  }
  if (v == 7) {
    update(dataset2)
  }
  if (v == 1) {
    update(dataset)
  }

})
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZyt8M8AFT2X37VcbP6H?p=preview).

Comment: I‘v rewritten my  code as yours,but x and y axis aren't update after I click selector option.code here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23581882/

Comment: Not very sure where you doing a mistake may be you need to console log the dataset coming in update, i have a hunch its not changing.

Comment: I can get the correct data in console log. All extra data display at the first  chart rectangle